# Encontrar nombres archivos en ruta

Tags: javascript, jquery

Dispongo de una carpeta contenedora de archivos, esos archivos los irá subiendo un usuario.

La ruta es conocida, pero el nombre y extensión de ese fichero no. Estoy intentando encontrar un método para realizarlo, pero o me encuentro con soluciones que incluyen el nombre del archivo o buscan la ruta.

Los ejemplos que encuentro son:

```
//Obtiene el nombre del archivo pero a partir de ruta completa
var pathname = "/Content/img/imagen.jpg"; 
var leafname = pathname.split('\\').pop().split('/').pop();
```

pero mi `pathname` sería:

```
var pathname = "/Content/img/";
```

**¿Cómo recojo los elementos que se encuentren dentro de esa ruta?**

Comment: No puedes acceder al sistema de ficheros desde un navegador, Tu única opción es que el usuario seleccione un fichero a traves de un input type='file'

Comment: No entiendo tu pregunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## No puedes

**Desde el lado cliente no está permitido por defecto.** Puedes configurarlo desde el servidor para permitir el acceso a la ruta o generar un método que invoque al servidor y desde ahí realizar la consulta de los archivos.

---

En mi caso, al ser una web asp.net con c# ha sido usando [`Directory.GetFiles()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getfiles?view=netcore-3.1#System_IO_Directory_GetFiles_System_String_) realizando la petición desde el lado cliente con un método ajax.

### Servidor:

```
public ActionResult ObtenerImagenDeRuta(string Codigo)
        {
            try
            {
                var imagen = Directory.GetFiles(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~" + Constantes.RUTA_IMGREFERENCIAS + Codigo + "/"));
                    
                return new JsonResult
                {
                    Data = imagen,
                    JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
                };
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                _log.Error(e);
                return null;
            }

        }
```

---

### Cliente:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'Controlador/ObtenerImagenDeRuta?Codigo=' + Codigo,
    success: function(respuesta) {
        //respuesta me devuelve json con los elementos
        $.each(respuesta, function(item, value){
            //elementos divididos
        });
    },
    error: function() {
        console.log("No se ha podido obtener la información");
    }
});
```